# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error (lldb)

Tags: objective-c

I'm developing an app and it has two image views. Each image view has its own button to select image from camera roll. When I click the button one it shows a camera roll and I select an image and it is displayed in the image view1 but when I click the second button to select image from camera roll and select image, it shows the image on the image view1 instead of imageview2. Does anyone know how to solve it???.This is my interface. I'm using Objective-c language.

[image]

here is the code :

```
- (IBAction)CNICFront:(id)sender { 
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; 
    picker.delegate=self; 
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]‌​;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
} 

- (IBAction)CNICBack:(id)sender { 
    pic = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; 
    pic.delegate=self; 
    pic setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]‌​; 
   [self presentViewController:pic animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
}
```

Delegate methods are for image view 1 is this: -

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{ 
     image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
     [self.imageView1 setImage:image]; 
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; 
 }

 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerControll‌​er *)picker{ 
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; 
 }
```

Comment: assume u have 2 image views v1 and v2 ...... in ur 2nd button action u given for setting the image v1.image=your pickedImage change to v2.image=your pickedImage.  or (From ur screen Shot)    I think u r given same action for 2 button same, in this case u need to use tag values of ur TakeAPic buttons

Comment: post ur code it easy to resolve your issue.?

Comment: - (IBAction)CNICFront:(id)sender {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)CNICBack:(id)sender {
    pic = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    pic.delegate=self;
    [pic setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:pic animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

Comment: Delegate methods are for image view 1 is this:                                                -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    
    image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self.imageView1 setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

Comment: and for imageview2 and choose image from button2 same methods but change the instants with image1 and UIImagePickerController *pic.

Comment: [self.imageView1 setImage:image];      u assigning the image for imagevew1 only u r not assigning image for imageView 2.

Comment: where is ur code for imageview2 assigning the image

Comment: when is choose image from button2 it shows image in imageview1 instead to imageview2

Comment: check my answer it will helps u if u get any issue comment bellow

Comment: u checked @Hamza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]**updated Code:** example

**.h file:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
- (IBAction)but1:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)but2:(UIButton *)sender;
```

**.m File file**

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
        UIImagePickerController *picker;
        NSString *ImageViewC;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
   picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;


    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    - (IBAction)but1:(UIButton *)sender {
        ImageViewC=@"1";

        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (IBAction)but2:(UIButton *)sender {
        ImageViewC=@"2";

        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

        UIImage * image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        if ([ImageViewC isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            [self.img1 setImage:image];
        }else{
            [self.img2 setImage:image];
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
    @end
```

Comment: This code is displaying image in imageView2. the actual is that if i click button1 it should show image in imageView1 and if i click on button2 it should display image in an imageView 2 @Naveen Kumar

Comment: viewdidload intilaze the ImageViewC string like ImageViewC=[[NSString alloc]init]; and please check the code I updated ... for assigning the value for ImageViewC.

Comment: this is working same as before when i click button1 it displaying image in imageView2 and when is click button2 and select image it displays image in imageView2

Comment: ok put break point in picker view and click ur first button and check the ImageViewC value comming 1 or not

Comment: It is working same. Can u please check the image of interface above and make a solution ???

Comment: still ur getting same issue ..?

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) ,  showing this error  and in debug  area it is showing this , class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView1.'